# Android Studio shortcut end line with semicolon

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the shortcut to end line with a semicolon in Android Studio?

[image]

One could click `End` and type the semicolon, but that would be a workaround.

I'm sure that there must a direct shortcut to end a line whichever the claret's position in said line, since Android Studio displays the offending un-ended line with a placeholder underlined in red.

Comment: alt+enter? 
google moved to a no semicolon language (kotlin) maybe changing languages will help?
I've searched for an answer to this question for a long while, and nothing satisfied my need so i just changed to kotlin ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cursor anywhere on the line at the end of which you want the semicolon, just press the following:

For Windows: `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

For Mac: `cmd` + `shift` + `enter`

Comment: Doesn't work on my Mac with a relatively freshly installed Android Studio 4.1.2.